# Super slow loop in python

Tags: python, pandas, numba

I am trying to loop over a pandas ds where each element is a text. I then apply a sentiment prediction function to predict the sentiment of the text. There are 12000 instances. I have tried running it on local machine, as well as amazon EC2 and google Colab but it is always extremely slow.

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("nlptown/bert-base-multilingual-uncased-sentiment")
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("nlptown/bert-base-multilingual-uncased-sentiment")


model.save_pretrained("./")
tokenizer.save_pretrained("./")


import torch
from numba import jit
from tqdm import tqdm

def helper(input):
      inputs = tokenizer(input, return_tensors="pt", padding=True, 
                         truncation=True, max_length=50, 
                         add_special_tokens = True)
      labels = torch.tensor([1]).unsqueeze(0)  # Batch size 1
      outputs = model(**inputs, labels=labels)
      outputs.logits 
      probs= torch.nn.functional.softmax(outputs.logits, 
                                         dim=1, 
                                         _stacklevel=3, 
                                         dtype=None)
      _max = torch.max(probs).item()
      _argmax = torch.argmax(probs).item()

      if _argmax < 2:
        return 2
      elif _argmax > 2:
        return 0
      else:
        return 1

@jit    
def predict(input):
    res = []
    for item in tqdm(input):
        sent = helper(item)
        res.append(sent)
    return res        

predict(list(data.utterances))
```

The output takes tens of minutes!!! Is there any way to do this under one minute?

Also, here are the warnings I am getting.

```
<ipython-input-55-71e31fd381d2>:26: NumbaWarning: 
Compilation is falling back to object mode WITH looplifting enabled because Function "predict" failed type inference due to: Untyped global name 'tqdm': Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'type'>

File "<ipython-input-55-71e31fd381d2>", line 29:
def predict(input):
    <source elided>
    res = []
    for item in tqdm(input):
    ^

  @jit
<ipython-input-55-71e31fd381d2>:26: NumbaWarning: 
Compilation is falling back to object mode WITHOUT looplifting enabled because Function "predict" failed type inference due to: Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'numba.core.dispatcher.LiftedLoop'>

File "<ipython-input-55-71e31fd381d2>", line 29:
def predict(input):
    <source elided>
    res = []
    for item in tqdm(input):
    ^

  @jit
/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/core/object_mode_passes.py:152: NumbaWarning: Function "predict" was compiled in object mode without forceobj=True, but has lifted loops.

File "<ipython-input-55-71e31fd381d2>", line 28:
def predict(input):
    res = []
    ^

  state.func_ir.loc))
/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/core/object_mode_passes.py:162: NumbaDeprecationWarning: 
Fall-back from the nopython compilation path to the object mode compilation path has been detected, this is deprecated behaviour.

For more information visit https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/deprecation.html#deprecation-of-object-mode-fall-back-behaviour-when-using-jit

File "<ipython-input-55-71e31fd381d2>", line 28:
def predict(input):
    res = []
    ^

  state.func_ir.loc))
<ipython-input-55-71e31fd381d2>:26: NumbaWarning: 
Compilation is falling back to object mode WITHOUT looplifting enabled because Function "predict" failed type inference due to: Untyped global name 'tqdm': Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'type'>

File "<ipython-input-55-71e31fd381d2>", line 29:
def predict(input):
    <source elided>
    res = []
    for item in tqdm(input):
    ^

  @jit
/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/core/object_mode_passes.py:152: NumbaWarning: Function "predict" was compiled in object mode without forceobj=True.

File "<ipython-input-55-71e31fd381d2>", line 29:
def predict(input):
    <source elided>
    res = []
    for item in tqdm(input):
    ^

  state.func_ir.loc))
/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/core/object_mode_passes.py:162: NumbaDeprecationWarning: 
Fall-back from the nopython compilation path to the object mode compilation path has been detected, this is deprecated behaviour.

For more information visit https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/deprecation.html#deprecation-of-object-mode-fall-back-behaviour-when-using-jit

File "<ipython-input-55-71e31fd381d2>", line 29:
def predict(input):
    <source elided>
    res = []
    for item in tqdm(input):
    ^

  state.func_ir.loc))
 11%|█         | 1275/12006 [08:40<7:45:34,  2.60s/it]
```

Comment: `outputs.logits` does nothing.  Is that a function you intended to call?

Comment: Which step takes the time?  You can't really optimize it unless you know where you are spending your time.

Comment: Start out with [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) to narrow down the slow parts of your code. You can call your script with `python -m cProfile </path/to/script.py>` and then sort it with something useful like `-s cumtime`. [Sort option list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#pstats.Stats.sort_stats)

Comment: @TimRoberts Adding onto his point. You can add timer to investigate which part of the code is running the slowest. Try import time; start=time.time();for loop; print(time.time()-start); You can sprinkle this around your code to breakdown the runtime.

Comment: The @jit decorator is useless here. It is not gonna work since your code is not supported by Numba (and will not be): tqdm and torch functions are external modules that are not plan to be supported. Not to mention the helper function would be to have a decorator too if it would be supported.